# From iterative function to recursive function

Tags: c

Can someone help me transform this function from iterative form to recursive form?. I'll be very grateful, because I'm not very good at recursion. Thanks in advance.
P.S my function turns vowels into the next letter of the alphabet, and consonants into the previous letter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void modifyString( char vowels[], char string[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
      string[i] = tolower(string[i]);
        if (strchr(vowels, string[i])) {
            string[i] += 1;
        } else if (isalpha(string[i])) {
            string[i] -= 1;
        }
    }  
}


int main() {

    char vow[]="aeiou",str[100];

    printf("String : ");
    fgets(str,sizeof str,stdin);

   modifyString(vow,str);

   printf("new string : %s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a recursive function is a good idea here? Because it isn't.

Comment: @Cheatah I don't believe that. It's just a task. But, why is it not a good idea?

Comment: What does the stack look like for a 1000 character string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/* The idea is you need some sort of relation between each
 * recursive calls. E.g. when you call modifyString(s),
 * you can manually modify the first character of s and let
 * the recursion handle the rest of the string.
 */
void modifyString( char vowels[], char string[]) {
    // The base case
    if (not string) return;

    // Now work on the first character
    string[0] = tolower(string[0]);
    if (strchr(vowels, string[0])) {
        string[0] += 1;
    } else if (isalpha(string[0])) {
        string[0] -= 1;
    }

    // Recursive call, after which string+1 will have been modified.
    modifyString(vowels, string+1);
```

Comment: `if (not *string) return;` or, my preference, `if (*string == 0) return;`

Comment: (a) Code without explanation is not a good answer. (b) Stack Overflow is not a personal coding service, and attempts to use it as such should not be rewarded. It is not good to just provide code to students who are not doing the assignment on their own. It is fine to teach a student who is not understanding an idea and is trying, but just handing code to a student that likely completes their assignment for a grade without regard to whether they understand it or not is not beneficial to the student, to the school, or to society.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hey thanks for your comment. Added some comments. Please let me know how you think.